# How to revive my android phone?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, boot-loop

So my phone is dead or whatever it is. It just show the logo screen showing that it will boot into recovery but after all it just turned off. The boot loader is locked so I had nothing to do. I removed the battery for 1 hour and insert it again then press the power button but nothing happens. Connected this to my laptop but still can not be recognized. I also connected it to my laptop without battery but it just shows up the logo then shuts down.


So this is what happens before all of this. I root then flash cwm using Flashify and reboots into recovery and it all started here. Stuck in a logo screen for infinite time. I tried to repair it to a phone repair centers but they can not do it. 


Now for the last time before I will consult it to the manufacturer,
 is there any solutions that I can do ? 
Well I have the stock ROM for this phone which is 5.0.1 


**Can I flash the ROM in this situation ? 

Can I access the internal storage in this time ?

Or any other suggestions, easy or very difficult steps ?**



Hoping for your help, Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing fastboot drivers on your computer, then try unlocking the boot loader and flashing a new recovery. But all data will be lost.

Comment: Yeah I can risk losing all of my data because I backed it up, But the problem is it wont recognize by my PC even I have all ADB drivers and my phone drivers

Comment: When you go to device manager on your computer, is there anything with a yellow exclamation mark?

Comment: Also, sometimes the universal adb drivers don't work, just incase you're using them

Comment: Yeah I also checked my device manager and there is no signs of android devices attach even no refreshing and loading signs

Comment: I'm assuming you have downloaded all the Google sdk and adb tools? Is there anything in device manager that may hint to anything? Have you tried a different USB port and cable?

Comment: Tried all my ports in my PC , downloaded all required drivers, android sdk are ready, But no signs inside device manager

Comment: Are you running cmd/terminal with elevated privileges?

Comment: I tried that recently but in only shows offline emulated device

Comment: Hmm.... I'm not sure. I'd go to the manufacturer for diagnostics.

Comment: Yeah that would be my last choice but thanks for responding !